# Multiple Boolean Filter in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have a settings node in a user with three boolean values and a three exact same values in an item. I want to filter the list of items based on the user setting on which to display.

I searched high and low and nothing seems to be working:

item:

```
{"cash_back": true,
  "miles": false,
  "points": false
}
```

user:

```
settings: {"cash_back": true,
  "miles": false,
  "points": true
}
```

html:

```
ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {cash_back: user.settings.cash_back, points: user.settings.points, miles: user.settings.miles} | limitTo: curLimit"
```

...but it does work if I have one

```
filter: {cash_back: user.settings.cash_back}
```

obviously just for that setting...

can anyone help on this?

**I would like to see all that are true (so if points and miles are true see all points and miles items even if there is a miles item with a points value of false)**

Comment: Your syntax looks correct.  Are you sure you have items that match the user settings?  All three settings would have to be identical between the settings and item.

Comment: What's not working?  item.points isn't equal to user.settings.points so nothing should appear

Comment: Here is a fiddle of your code: https://jsfiddle.net/pbeoy2oh/ It seems to be working. You may need to learn [ask] and provide a [mcve] yourself

Comment: I would like to see the items that are true.

Comment: So if the settings are set to ttf, I want to see all the cash_back and miles - it will be rare that an item will have two or more true values.

Comment: Anyone know how to show all items that have a true value as in my comment above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out on my own. (One thing to note is in my user node I keep track of a list of item ids - the reason for the initial for loop) I set up a filtering function and compared the two boolean values ( I separated each into an if statement for debugging and tracking results - this can be cleaned up later.)

function:

```
$scope.settingsFilter = function(card){
     var temp = {};
     for(c in $scope.cards){
       if ($scope.cards[c].id === card){
         temp = $scope.cards[c];
         break;
       }
     }
     if(($scope.user.settings.cash_back == true && temp.cash_back == true)){
       return true;
     }
     if(($scope.user.settings.points == true && temp.points == true)){
       return true;
     }
     if(($scope.user.settings.miles == true && temp.miles == true)){
       return true;
     }else{
       return false;
     }
     return false;
}
```

html:

```
ng-repeat="card in userCards | filter:settingsFilter track by $index"
```